# Jinja2: render template inside template

Tags: python, jinja2

Is it possible to render a Jinja2 template inside another template given by a string? For example, I want the string

```
{{ s1 }}
```

to be rendered to

```
Hello world
```

given the following dictionary as a param for `Template.render`:

```
{ 's1': 'Hello {{ s2 }}', 's2': 'world' }
```

I know the similar process can be done with `include` tag separating the content of `s1` to the another file, but here I don't want to follow that way.

Comment: How would `s2` know that it's substitution comes from that dictionary? Similar question - what if that was `Hello {{ s1 }}`

Comment: @cricket_007 I admit there seems to be no way to know that. And this also explains why this cannot be done with current mechanism..

Comment: You might be able to loop over that dictionary values, rendering them with the dictionary itself, but it'd get messy outside this simple example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not have an environment to easily test these ideas, but am exploring something similar within airflow's use of jinja templates.

From what I can find the best way to do this is do *explicitly* render the inner template string within the outer template. To do this you may need to pass or import [the Template constructor](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template) in the param dictionary.

Here is some (untested) code:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template_string = '{{ Template(s1).render(s2=s2) }}'
outer_template = Template(template_string)
outer_template.render( 
    s1='Hello {{ s2 }}', 
    s2='world',
    Template=Template
)
```

---

This is not nearly as clean as you were hoping for, so we may be able to take things further by creating a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) so we can use it like this:

```
{{ s1|inner_render({"s2":s2}) }}
```

Here is a custom filter I think will do the job:

```
from jinja2 import Template
def inner_render(value, context):
    return Template(value).render(context)
```

---

Now let's assume we want the same context as the outer template, and - what the heck - lets render an arbitrary number of levels deep, `N`. Hopefully some example usages will look like:

```
{{ s1|recursive_render }}

{{ s3|recursive_render(2) }}
```

An easy way to get the context from our custom filter is to use the [contextfilter decorator](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.contextfilter)

```
from jinja2 import Template
from jinja2 import contextfilter
@contextfilter
def recursive_render(context, value, N=1):
    if N == 1:
        val_to_render = value
    else:
        val_to_render = recursive_render(context, value, N-1)
    return Template(value).render(context)
```

Now you can do something like `s3 = '{{ s1 }}!!!'` and `{{ s3|recursive_render(2) }}` should render to `Hello world!!!`. I suppose you could go even deeper and detect how many levels to render by counting brackets.

---

Having gone through all this I would like to explicitly point out that **this is very confusing**.

Although I do believe I have found a need for 2 levels of rendering within my very specific airflow usage, I cannot imagine a need for more levels than that.

If you are reading this thinking "this is just what I need": Whatever you are trying to do can probably be done more eloquently. Take a step back, consider that you may have an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and re-read jinja's docs to be sure there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always create a filter like:

```
@app.template_filter('t')
def trenderiza(value, obj):
  rtemplate = Environment(loader=BaseLoader()).from_string(value)
  return rtemplate.render(**obj)
```

so if

```
s1="Hello {{s2}}"
```

you can filter from the template as:

```
 <p>{{s1|t(dict(s2='world')}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the low-level Jinja API for this, stolen from Ansible core.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Stolen from Ansible, thus licensed under GPLv3+.

from collections.abc import Mapping
from jinja2 import Template

# https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/13c28664ae0817068386b893858f4f6daa702052/lib/ansible/template/vars.py#L33
class CustomVars(Mapping):
    '''
    Helper class to template all variable content before jinja2 sees it. This is
    done by hijacking the variable storage that jinja2 uses, and overriding __contains__
    and __getitem__ to look like a dict.
    '''

    def __init__(self, templar, data):
        self._data = data
        self._templar = templar

    def __contains__(self, k):
        return k in self._data

    def __iter__(self):
        keys = set()
        keys.update(self._data)
        return iter(keys)

    def __len__(self):
        keys = set()
        keys.update(self._data)
        return len(keys)

    def __getitem__(self, varname):
        variable = self._data[varname]
        return self._templar.template(variable)

# https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/13c28664ae0817068386b893858f4f6daa702052/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L661
class Templar:

    def __init__(self, data):

        self._data = data

    def template(self, variable):

        '''
        Assume string for now.
        TODO: add isinstance checks for sequence, mapping.
        '''

        t = Template(variable)
        ctx = t.new_context(CustomVars(self, self._data), shared=True) # shared=True is important, not quite sure yet, why.
        rf = t.root_render_func(ctx)

        return "".join(rf)

t_str = "{{ s1 }}"
data = { 's1': 'Hello {{ s2 }}', 's2': 'world' }

t = Templar(data)
print("template result: %s" % t.template(t_str))
```

```
template result: Hello world
```